# Tagging a protected branch

Tags: github

Problem: I have a protected branch that requires PR reviews to push to. However I also need to push tags to this branch. However, tags cannot be included in PR reviews.

Is it possible to create a rule that allows code contributors to push tags to a protected branch, but still keep the branch protected from direct code pushs?

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is to:

- push your tags to a non-protected branch
- associate a GitHub Action which would then push those tags to the protected branch.

The second action would be done with a dedicated user who will be [authorized to push to a protected branch](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-11-19-allow-bypassing-required-pull-requests/).